# Firefox Netscape incompatability

Tags: firefox

have searched previously asked questions but still not getting quite the answers I need.

I built wwww.broadstairsfoodfestival.org.uk in DreamWeaver 8.

Ran both the page code and CSS through W3C to clean up any errors.

Ive looked at Check Target Browser in DW but all looks clean.

However Preview in Browser shows problems.

On some pages blocks of text flash; on others its the paragraph title that flashes . .  and I'm damned if i can see what to chnage.

Help!
....................................

Comment: The URL you've posted is inaccessable - perhaps you should open it to public access if you wish to have this question answered?

Comment: @Seidr There's a additional `w` in the `www` :)

Comment: Urg... `blink` *and* `marquee` on the same page. I feel like puking...

Comment: Hah - 9AM, my eyes have not adjusted yet!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `text-decoration: blink` from
   the styles applied to some of the
   elements and the blinking will stop.
2. Please do not use **any** the following:

   - Tables for layout
   - Marquee for scrolling headlines
   - The blink `text-decoration` property or the `blink` element
   - Dreamweaver's WYSIWYG mode. Especially a version that is as old as 8
3. Stop referring to Firefox as Netscape. One is the second most popular browser on the web today, the other an old outdated browser from the era of the First Browser Wars.

That is all.

Comment: Text-decoration blink was never intended.

. . .and was added accidentally. Curiously it didnt show in IE or I would have spotted it straight away.

Fine for you to say "dont use Tables for layout"  but I it is what I know and at this precise point, I dont have the time to learn div layouts.

. . . so please have some sympathy for us dinasours who are trying to keep up....................but thanks for pointing out the blinking obvious.

Comment: @user431552: Hey, that's our job ;) And I think most of the users on this site would assure you, that moving away from tables is far easier than you make it out to be.

Comment: sorry if I was tetchy. . . .yes, it is your job and I'm grateful for your expertise. ive just bought a SitePoint book called "Everything you know about CSS is wrong!"  which is a basically a tutorial in DIV layer construction so I have taken heed . . I'll let you know how I get on.